# Ubuntu vs. Kubuntu vs. Xubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, xubuntu

Is there a link or any side-by-side comparisons detailing why one would choose Kubuntu or Xubuntu over Ubuntu? I am running on a somewhat older machine (Dell optilplex 745 tower), so how would this figure into the decision?

Comment: Just install the `xubuntu-desktop` and `kubuntu-desktop` and find out!

Comment: I'll save you a lot of time: Xubuntu. Fast, snappy, easy to work with, convenient, yet full of feautures. (Okay, reasonable amount of features.) No need to thank!

Comment: Many many things on ubuntu website : https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours

Answer (score 16):

I don't have a link handy but the main differences are the following:

Ubuntu:

- Main distribution
- Uses Unity as the desktop environment
- Close to what people sees when people says "Linux desktop"

Kubuntu:

- Uses KDE as the desktop environment
- Pretty-looking. I personally describe it as a Mac OS X/Windows hybrid, visually speaking.
- Generally slower on lower end/older hardware
- Might use more disk space.
- Has the best MIME-Type association system/launcher, in my humble opinion. (kde-open)

Xubuntu:

- Uses XFCE as the desktop environment
- XFCE <strike>is a fork of the old GNOME desktop</strike>, resembles GNOME 2 in appearance, aimed at being lightweight but still usable.
- runs decently on lower end/old hardware
- Not exactly "super fast", but <strike>better</strike> faster than GNOME/Unity/KDE

There's also Lubuntu and Fluxbuntu which are using different desktop environments, respectively LXDE and Fluxbox. Fluxbox would be the fastest and lightest, but not exactly user-friendly, especially if you come from another non-unix-line Operating System.
Other distributions that are lighter and that might work better depending on how old and powerful this computer is, but I will let you do the research about those.

As noted in this answer's comments, LXDE is not actively developed anymore.

Comment: XFCE == LXDE in terms of speed. Except Xfce got more features. LXDE is not even getting commits anymore, it's literally been dead for a year or so. (Only PcMan working on his file manager.) RazorQt is the same. Just go with Xfce.

Comment: Xfce is *not* a fork of Gnome 2. Not by far.

Comment: I thought it was. My bad.